# Is it possible to duplicate outputs 1 and 2 to outputs 3 and 4 on a Scarlett 2i4?

Tags: audio-interfaces

I currently have a 2i2, and it's good. I also have some slightly higher impedance headphones (250) and the headphone amp on it needs a little more power. I'm getting an O2 headphone amp, and I'd like to connect it to my interface, but the 2i2 only has one set of outputs that I currently have wired to my monitors. The 2i4 solves this by having 2 sets of outputs, but the problem here is that I have to manually set which output to send audio to.

What I need to know is whether there's a way to set, for example, my Windows audio output to the Scarlett 2i4 and have it come out of both sets of outputs simultaneously. Ideally I can use my monitors as normal but also be able to pick up and use my headphones without having to fiddle with setting audio outputs since I will be using this outside of a DAW as well.

Comment: Are you using the Focusrite mixer software? That should let you do it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Is that available with the 2i4? I don't actually have it yet, but I don't see a download for it on the software page.

Answer (score 2):

Focusrite support have confirmed to me that this hardware does not support outputting to 2x2 channels using normal WDM audio drivers - this means no 4-channel output for YouTube, for example. Any application which can use the ASIO drivers can have complete control over all four channels, for example, a DAW.

However, you can use a software which acts as a bridge between a WDM driver and the ASIO drivers for your soundcard, which creates a fake sound device in Windows which then drives 2x2 channels on your Scarlett. The software I purchased is http://odeus-audio.com.au/Odeus/ASIOLinkPro, but there may be others.

Seems to work well so far. It introduces some latency, but quality and functionality seem spot on. You will have to drag some lines around to set your outputs, but it's reasonably intuitive.